# React table with built-in search mechanism

Tags: reactjs

I need to use a react table with search feature in it, similar to that of jQuery's datatable. What I need is a teatarea, that when I type some substring in it, the rows of the table are being filtered by it. Is there anything like this?

Answer (score 2):

[Reactable](https://github.com/glittershark/reactable#sorting) should do the trick. It has sorting, filtering, etc...

Basic React component usage:

```
var Table = Reactable.Table;
ReactDOM.render(
    <Table className="table" data={[
        { Name: 'Griffin Smith', Age: 18 },
        { Age: 23,  Name: 'Lee Salminen' },
        { Age: 28, Position: 'Developer' },
    ]} />,
    document.getElementById('table')
);
```